How to deal with disabled root
How to solve this
How to solve this
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/sudo: line 313: /sbin/su: No such file or directory
Ability to run this command as root has been disabled permanently for safety purposes.
I tried to install aircrack-ng on termux but it couldn't

See https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/rouhqg/how_can_i_fix_this_i_cant_seem_to_use_the_sudo/.  You can't root Termux.

Make the script named "su" or "sudo" and use it to forward last command to the bash or what do you like and put it to the sbin folder.
